# Select2 loading page with existing value

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

Trying to load an edit profile page for a musician site. There is a select2 box that lists the instruments that the user plays, and it pulls this information from the database. But I can't figure out how to get the existing instrument list to display on the select2 on render, it always displays as an empty select2 box (the actual search and select functionality of the box works).

(this is coffeescript in meteor)

On render, it runs:

```
populator = Meteor.user().profile.instrumentsPlayed

 $("#e9").select2()
```

the populator variable defines properly and has a value of

```
["acoustic guitar", "piano", "ukulele", "piano"]
```

I've tried many variations including:

```
$("#e9").select2("value", populator)
```

None of the variations worked, and I have a hard time finding and implementing the exact thing I need from the select2 documentation... can someone point me in the right direction?

Summary: need to load select2 box with existing data instead of just empty select2 box

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation here: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#programmatic

They use "val" and not "value" to programmatically set the values.

Try this:

```
 $('#e9').select2();
 $('#e9').select2('val', populator);
```

edit:
Perhaps the confusion was the `select2()` should be called before `select2("val",...)`.

Here is a jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/JFMbt/  showing both methods (comment out one of them)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try that as well, but it didn't work for me. What ended up working was 

$('#e9').val(populator).select2

Comment: ah I see, that would work also.  I created a jsfiddle to show both methods work - edited answer